# How to Avoid OR condition in lambda expression

Tags: list, linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I am new to the lambda expression. I came across a list of type string where I have to query on the basis of certain keywords. I can use multiple OR condition but that's not how I want to do.

Here is the snippet:

```
List<string> messageList = new List<string>(); 
//add some data to this list
.
.
//now query
var message = messageList.Where(x => x.Contains("SomeValue") && (x.Contains(value_1)) || (x.Contains(value_2))).ToList();
```

In the above code the OR list might go on...

In case I have all these values (to be used in OR) in a List, do we have some generic way to avoid these OR condition and query this list instead

Any help in this regard would be appreciated

Comment: You might be looking for the [Enumerable.Any Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Any` on the list of words to check:

```
var words = new [] {value_1, value_2, ...};

var message = messageList.Where(x => x.Contains("SomeValue") 
                                  && words.Any(w => x.Contains(w))
                         .ToList();
```